# Synching package indexes across identical computers

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, apt-cache

Is it safe to copy the package index files (which get updated when I run `apt-get update`) from one computer to another identical one? Basically, I've run `apt-get update` on one of them, and I don't want to have to run it again from the other computer because I have slow and limited internet. I've copied the packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` from one system to another before, and it worked just fine; no download was necessary. I'd like to  not have to update the package indexes as well.

I believe the index files are at `/var/lib/apt/lists/`

Answer (score 1):

Um, no, that's not really a safe thing to do. What I have done in the past is run the following on a "master" computer that has everything installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

Then ship the installed-software file around on a USB key or somesuch, running the following on each "slave" computer I want the same set of software on:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < installed-software
sudo dselect install
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the installed software of the source system the best way to do this is using:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v -E 'deinstall|hold' > installed-packages
```

Then in the target system run:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < installed-packages
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

This way you get sure that the target system don't get some packages uninstalled/holded.